# C# Object derivation

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

According to specification:

> "All classes in the .NET Framework are derived from Object"

How are classes derived from object base class without explicitly writing the Object class as parent?

I.E.:

```
public sealed class String : IComparable, ICloneable, IConvertible, IEnumerable, IComparable<string>, IEnumerable<char>, IEquatable<string>
```

Comment: It is implied since it is true by definition ("All classes in the .NET Framework are derived from Object"). It is a bit like saying 'all of my kids are human'. I don't have to specify it explicitly - since it is true by definition. _Think of it the other way around - if that specification was true (which it is) what would be the **value** of forcing you to specify that it inherited from object? There would be no benefit - thus it isn't required._

Comment: [Base classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#base-classes): "When a `class_type` is included in the `class_base`, it specifies the direct base class of the class being declared. If a class declaration has no `class_base`, or if the `class_base` lists only interface types, the direct base class is assumed to be `object`"

Comment: Ok, i can understand this, but how, from the technical point of view, is this obtained?

Comment: Imagine how it would be obtained if you inherited from Object explicitly. It is obtained the exact same way - without you having to specify it inherits from Object explicitly. _In other words, whether it is implicit or explicit makes no difference to how it is implemented._

Comment: Writing `class Foo { }` is short-hand for writing `class Foo : object { }`. It's as simple as that. It's compiler trickery!

Comment: Ok, thank you, guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another note: All those basic methods you can access are implemented in every class/type:

Equals, ReferenceEquals, GetHashCode, GetType, ToString.

This implies that there is always a hidden inheritance from System.Object. "object" is merely an alias - when you select "object" in VS, it will also highlight all System.Object classes to indicate identity (and vice versa). It seems to be hard implemented into C# and I guess inevitable to inherit from 'object'. It's the foundation which allows you to access *anything* with, no matter what it is - even though you barely can do anything with it without casting it back.

```
object x = new *anything*;
```

Also, abstract class instances can not be assigned, but that's on the end of 'abstract' to actively prevent it, not on 'object' to receive it.

If object would work any otherwise, you'd have to inherit from 'System.Object' with all base classes, which would be tedious and pointless. Object is not meant to be excluded anyway, as it would cause a great loss due to having no certain way to refer to *things* any more when it would make sense (and it did for me today when I wrote a class to gather objects, filter out nulls and output their ToString() in a formatted string for debugging purposes).

Another interesting point is that 'object' could be made abstract, so that object x = new object (); does no longer work. Because what is object anyway? It's nothing really, but still something. It's less information than a bool variable yields. But the C# developers decided not to do that, which seems to result in more simplicity. Also there is/are no good/sufficient reason(s) to forbid it.